# How can I use natural language processing to split a sentence in half?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

I've never done natural language processing, so please excuse any wrong terminology. I'm open to using any language/library such as NLTK or spaCy, but no paid API.

I'm trying to make a game where the user has to finish a famous quote with their own.

Example input:

> A room without books is like a body without a soul.

Desired output:

> A room without books...

I'd like to be able more complex sentences such as:

> I've learned that people will forget what you said, people will forget what you did, but people will never forget how you made them feel.

Desired output:

> I've learned that people will forget what you said...

Another example:

> Don’t walk in front of me… I may not follow
>
> Don’t walk behind me… I may not lead
>
> Walk beside me… just be my friend

Desired output:

> Don’t walk in front of me… I may not follow...

I feel like extracting noun/verb phrases/chunks is almost what I want, but not quite. Maybe something like (pseudocode):

```
phrases = extractAllPhrases(sentence)
middlePhrase = phrases.length / 2
desiredOutuput = sentence.substring(0, sentence.offset(middlePhrase) + middlePhrase.length))
```

Is this too complicated to achieve using NLP? Are there too many syntactical variables in the English language to cover to get consistent results? Should I just manually split up the quotes? I'm open to suggestions instead of working answers, like "Read up on blah blah", I just don't know where to even begin. But I'd like to know if this is feasible before I spend a lot of time learning NLP just to find out this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

well, this is can be done without using NLP. Here is the python code..

```
sentence = "A room without books is like a body without a soul."
sentence_list = sentence.split(" ")
length = len(sentence_list)
output = sentence_list[0:round(length/2)]
print(" ".join(output)+"...")
```

Comment: I wanted to use NLP because I didn't want to just split the sentence in half arbitrarily. I wanted to split it at a logical section, i.e. after a noun phrase. But seeing your code work makes me think I might not need to do that anymore. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more shorter form of it. you can try this code

```
sentence = "A room without books is like a body without a soul."
truncate_text = (sentence[:40] + '....') if len(sentence) > 40 else sentence
print(truncate_text)
```